$k$-th power of spanning tree
I note that there are many papers which study $k$-th power of Hamilton cycle or path.
But there is no paper about $k$-th power of spanning tree with bounded degree (spanning tree with bounded degree can be seen as a generalization of Hamilton path.)
Does anyone know why? This motivation seems natural.
